# how to make conditional statement(if is "1" of "7", then) on node.tpl.php? Drupal 6.2 or how to move this to page.tpl.php effectively?

Tags: php, drupal-6, conditional-statements

Im trying to create a conditional statement that iterates through an array of nodes on node.tpl.php for Drupal 6.2.

what I want is a statement that allows something like:
If this item is "1" of "7" do this: "";
If this item is "2" of "7" do this: "";
If this item is "3" of "7" do this: "";
If this item is "4" of "7" do this: "";
If this item is "5" of "7" do this: "";
If this item is "6" of "7" do this: "";
If this item is "7" of "7" do this: "";
and repeat this sequence.

I need this type of split to display a grid of uniquely sized rectangles that repeat in a series of 7 items, over and over.
this is my reference page built in html that Im trying to make into a dynamic home page:
http://sidecha.in/fluidgrid1.html

Im using different imagecache presets that need to be loaded into each item in the array. so the end result should create a array of 7 items with unique imagecache settings for each item.
this is what i need turned into an array so I can assign different imagecache presets:

```
<div class="a3 <?php print $node->nid; ?>" id="e"><div class="maphomeimage">
<div class="maphomeoverlay" style="background-image:url(<?php print $url = imagecache_create_path('primary-thumb', $node->field_featured_image[0]['filepath']); ?>);">
```

" title="">

Comment: What's wrong with an [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) or a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)? Have you tried anything? Do you have some more concrete code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something close to [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280598/dan-grossman)'s answer :

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    $index = ($index + 1) % 7; 

    // print your item here using $index however you want
}
```

or

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    switch ($index++ % 7) {
         case 0: 
            // TODO item 1 of 7
            break;
         case 1: 
            // TODO item 2 of 7
            break;
         // ...
         case 6: 
            // TODO item 7 of 7
            break;
    }
}
```

** **UPDATE** **

So... I'm not too sure if this will work for you or not, but here would be what you'd need to do:

```
<?php
$count = /* TODO: INSERT CODE THAT RETURN THE NUMBER OF NODES HERE */;
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
   $column = $i % 7;    // column will be 0,1,2,3,4,5, or 6 only (see modulus math operator)

   $id = /* TODO: INSERT CODE THAT RETURN THE NODE ID HERE */;
   $bg_url = /* TODO: INSERT CODE THAT RETURN THE BACKGROUND IMAGE URL HERE */;
   $node_url = /* TODO: INSERT CODE THAT RETURN THE NODE IMAGE URL HERE */;
   $title = /* TODO: INSERT CODE THAT RETURN THE NODE TITLE HERE */;
?>
<div class="a3 <?php print $id; ?>" id="e-<?php print $id; ?>">
  <div class="maphomeimage">
    <div class="maphomeoverlay" style="background-image:url(<?php print $bg_url; ?>);">
      <p><a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $title ?>"><?php print $title ?></a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}  // end for $i
?>
```

Basically, replace anything between `/* ... */` with the code needed. Where

- `$i` is the node index from 0 to `$count`
- `$column` is the column index from 0 to 6. Replace code by `$column = ($i % 7) + 1;` to have the values from 1 to 7.
- You can get the row with `$row = floor($i / 7);`

Also note that this code will not display in columns, you'll need to apply a distinct CSS class for each container.

Since each HTML elements should have their own ID, I modified your HTML and replaced `id="e"` to `id="e<?php print $id; ?>"`. Just make sure that `$id` is always a valid HTML id value, or remove the `id` attribute at all.

Comment: i dont understand how this goes into my node.tpl.php file? I tried putting this in there and commenting out the quotation marks but that was a no go. I just get a blank screen. how do you make this code into separate statements so i dont have to comment out html code? or am i missing something?

Comment: Of course copy/pasting this code "as is" won't work, this is not a pre-digested solution, but a general idea of what you asked for (i.e. "repeat in a series of 7 items") as for your template files, I've never really worked with Drupal... *sigh* although your original question was not so precise and this answer is a "design suggestion" to split your iterations into chunks of "series of 7 items". I assume you have a basic understanding of PHP and know how to apply this solution in your problem. The actual solution would involve knowing what you actually have tried...

Comment: ... and not only a jumble of mixed PHP+HTML unformatted, undocumented code that has no iteration block whatsoever. No offense.

Comment: Im sorry if I was not clear or well formed with my question. this is my first question on stackoverflow and Im not good at all with php. Im a designer.

Comment: programmers are not designers and vice versa. No disrespect implied. I updated my answer. If this doesn't help, stackoverflow might not be the place for this question, and you may want to find some programmer to help you out with your actual project. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of `$things` you want to display in groups of 7:

```
$j = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($things); $i++) {

    if ($i > 0 && $i % 7 == 0) 
        $j = 1;

    $item = $things[$i];

    if ($j == 1) {
        //1 of 7
    } else if ($j == 2) {
        //2 of 7
    } else if ($j == 3) {
        //3 of 7
    ...
}
```

Comment: how do i get the items into the array? i tried the code but im keep getting a blank screen.

Comment: I have no idea what your template looks like. I don't know how you access your data. I just gave you an algorithm for doing what you need to do.